# Bitmap file fails to open

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap, android-bitmap

I run the following command and it always returns null as the Bitmap file fails to open for some reason. Please help!

```
const XCHAR* szFilePathW = L"C:\\Users\\Simrat\\Desktop";
std::ofstream bmpF;
    char szFilePathA[MSO_MAX_PATH]; // std::ofstream.open() takes char* in Android C++ compiler, whereas it takes both char* and wchar* in VC++
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, szFilePathW, -1, szFilePathA, MSO_MAX_PATH, NULL, NULL);
    bmpF.open(szFilePathA, std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::out);
    if (!bmpF.is_open())
        return null;
```

The functionality of the WideCharToMultiByte() function could be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your file path is botched.

Comment: `L"C:\\Users\\Simrat\\Desktop";` is a directory  I'd put money that you're expected to pass in a file

Comment: Also Windows doesn't accept UTF8 path. Use UTF16 or ANSI

Comment: Yes, and since Windows' version of std::ofstream::open has a `const wchar_t *` overload for the filename, you don't need to convert your filename to multibyte at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you appear to be missing a filename.  And the code should simply be:

```
const WCHAR* szFilePath = L"C:\\Users\\Simrat\\Desktop\\name_of_bitmap_file_I_want_to_create.bmp";
std::ofstream bmpF;
bmpF.open (szFilePath, std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::out);
```

No need to convert to multibyte, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z434859.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#basic_ofstream__open) (note that `open` has a `const wchar_t *` overload for the filename parameter - on Windows).